# SQL select largest 10 entries by data in many-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, relationship

I have a SQL database set up with a User object, a Guild object, and a GuildMember object. Users can be in many guilds and guilds can have many users so the GuildMember object links them. The User object contains a value for their current balance of money and I'm looking for a way to get the richest users in a specific guild. Right now I'm just getting all users from the guild and sorting it myself but there could be up to 100k users in a guild and this seems incredibly inefficient. Is there a way to have SQL do more of the work? Basically I'm just trying to figure out a single statement to return the top 10 or so richest users from a Guild ID. I'm running a MySQL database.

Model:

User --> GuildMember <-- Guild

id: string | UID: string | id: string

econ: int | GID: string | other data

I've been using Sequelize (though I'm very open to using a prepared SQL statement instead) and this is my current system in TypeScript:

```js
public static async getTop(guildId: string, num: number) {
  return Db.Guild.findByPk(guildId, { include: [{ model: Db.User, attributes: ['id', 'econ'] }] })
  .then(guild => (<UserInstance[]>guild.Users).sort((a, b) => b.econ - a.econ).slice(0, num));
}
```

Sample data:

User: id: 1, econ: 10

User: id: 2, econ: 3

...

User: id: 7, econ 12

### --

Guild: id: 1, other data

Guild: id: 2, other data

### --

GuildMember: UserId: 1, GuildId: 2

GuildMember: UserId 7, GuildId: 2

### --

Expected output from querying richest in guild 2: [User 7, User 1].

Obviously this is a very simplified example as users may belong to multiple guilds and there will thousands of users per guild. I need to return the top 10.

Comment: sounds simple enough, but without sample script makes it more difficult to understand.  do you have the script you've started with?

Comment: I've been using sequelize so I'm simply executing a select by primary key for the guild and including every User object linked. I then handle the sorting on the client side.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with your expected output from them?